# How google sorts the applications in a public developer/publisher google play profile?

Tags: google-play

How google sorts the applications in a public developer/publisher google play profile?

I want my most important applications first in the store.

Comment: i think its based on number of downloads

Comment: Currently, our first application is the one with less downloads, and the next one its not the one with most downloads or least downloads. I dont think it is based on n of downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've published your apps you can do this in the developer page settings in the [Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6226441?hl). This lets you feature the apps you think are most important.

For all non-featured apps, Play decides how to order them. This may change in time, and is done to try and maximize value to the user, so may even be different for different users.

Comment: There you can just feature an application. You cant change the order.

Comment: I've clarified the order a bit. Basically it is like all Play store search results - constantly being changed trying to give the best value to users.